# How do I add a new item into my database with 3 joined tables in EFCore/C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to add a new employee to my database.

I have a SQL database with 3 tables: Companies, Teams, Employees.

I have a list of companies in the database. Each company has several teams. Each team has several employees.

The three tables are joined (I think that's the term) and I used Entity Framework Core (for .NET Core 3.1) to do so with a code-first approach. Right now I'm able to populate a List<> of companies using data from my SQL tables correctly using one line of code. Great!

**Let's say I wanted to add a new Employee, Austin, to Microsoft's Marketing team?**

How do I go about this?

I don't think I can just add a new row into the Employee table and expect it to join properly with the Company and Team tables.

```
class Company
{
    [Key]
    int id; 
    string CompanyName;

    List<Team> Teams;
}
class Team
{
    [Key]
    int Id;
    string TeamName;

    List<Employee> Employees;
}
class Employee
{
    [Key]
    int Id;
    string EmployeeName;
}

void Main()
{
    // Context for my SQL database
    DbContext db = new DbContext();

    // Populate list of companies (and their respective teams and employees) from the SQL database
    List<Company> companies = db.Companies.Include(company => company.Teams).ThenInclude(team => team.Employees).ToList();

    // At this point 'companies' is populated and structured correctly. Each company in the list has a few teams. And each of those teams has a few employees. Great!

    // Let's say I want 'someEmployee' to be added to the Microsoft company's Marketing team

    // How do I add this employee to the database so that they are joined to the right company and team?
    Employee someEmployee = new Employee();

    // Code for adding the employee into the database here...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If it a new employee then you first add new employee. Then add row to the table which represents employee and team association by doing `team.Employees.Add(employee)` and saving the team.

Answer (score 0):

Let EF [entity change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) do the job for you:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    // Context for my SQL database
    MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

    // Populate list of companies (and their respective teams and employees) from the SQL database
    List<Company> companies = db.Companies.Include(company => company.Teams).ThenInclude(team => team.Employees).ToList();

    // At this point 'companies' is populated and structured correctly. Each company in the list has a few teams. And each of those teams has a few employees. Great!

    // Let's say I want 'someEmployee' to be added to the Microsoft company's Marketing team

    // How do I add this employee to the database so that they are joined to the right company and team?
    Employee someEmployee = new Employee()
    {
        Id = 1, // you probably will have your Ids auto-generated, my quick example didn't cater for that
        EmployeeName = "Austin"
    };

    var team = companies.Single(c => c.CompanyName == "Microsoft").Teams.Single(t => t.TeamName == "Microsoft Marketing"); // how you select the target team is not very important as long as it's been loaded by EF (which you do above)

    team.Employees.Add(someEmployee);
    db.Entry(someEmployee).State = EntityState.Added; // this is the only bit of work you have to do: tell EF change tracker this is a new entity so it should be inserted
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Code for adding the employee into the database here...
    // ...
}
```